# Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function: array-callback-return

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a couple of actions on a function to extract unix time at midnight, I map through the array and then filter by those values that modulus to 0. However I keep getting this pesky error msg, regardless of whether I return the map function or not..
Code below:

```
  midnightFunction = arr => {
    return arr.map(v =>
      v.filter(t => {
        if (t.published_at % 86400 === 0) {
          return t;
        };
      }
      )
    );
  };
```

My array is an array and looks like this:

```
[[{published_at: 1578960000, value: 20.41}, {published_at: 1578960000, value: 20.41},...etc ], [], []...], [[], [], []...] , ... etc
```

I want the result to have the same structure, but return just those values that match the condition.

```
t.published_at % 86400 === 0
```

Comment: please add `arr`. and the wanted result.

Comment: Yeah, what is the result/error that you are recieving... also, what are the contents of your array as @NinaScholz suggests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you pass to `array.filter()` should always return a truthy or falsy value. In your current code, if `t.published_at % 86400` is not zero, the function doesn't return any value (it returns undefined). Additionally, if that value *is* zero, instead of returning something like true/false it returns the element itself.

Your function should be as simple as this:

```js
const midnightFunction = arr => arr.map(v => v.filter(t => t.published_at % 86400 === 0));

//for demonstration
let data = [[{published_at: 1578960000, value: 20.41}, {published_at: 1578970000, value: 23.21}],[{published_at: 1578873601, value: 14.01}, {published_at: 1578873600, value: 27.25}]];
console.log(midnightFunction(data));
```

Comment: btw, `t` is still truthy. it is just a minor error.

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes, but it's rather un-idiomatic. Why `return t;` instead of `return true;`? The intent seems to be mangled.